# How do I get npm to start?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, command-line

I am currently trying to get npm to work with a github project and am very new to the GitHub scene. Currently working on Windows 10 in the Command Prompt.

The installation with `npm install` seemed to work fine, but when I try to `npm run` directly after installing, I get a whole list of errors.

Everything builds fine except for this one thing:

`./js/content.js 740 bytes {0} [built] [11 errors]`

and the error messages I get all are formatted as follows:

`ERROR in ./js/content.js

Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../content/home.md in C:\Users\My_Name\Desktop\FILE\file-folder/js
@ ./js/content.js 6:10-39'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] & [mcve].

Comment: If you are willing to provide github repo URL please provide here.. we can check it